# Topology with only one open proper set

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, terminology

What is the name of the Topologies that contains only one proper open set?
That is if X<>{ } and T={{ }, O,X} ,where O ⊂ X   ..I looking for a 
terminology  that represent this topology in general.For me I call them 
Non-Trivial minimal Topologies .But this is not scientific terminology?
please I f there an answer must be supported by a reference ?

Comment: I would rather call it *non-trivial* open set.

Comment: @drhab I looking for the  "official " mathematical terminology for them .If it exist

Answer (score 9):

An infraspace is a topology such that the only topology strictly coarser than it is the trivial topology. Every infraspace topology has on $E$ the form $\{E,A,\emptyset\}$ where $A \subset E$,  $A \neq \emptyset$, $A \neq E$.

[ROCKY MOUNTAIN JOURNAL OF MATHEMATICS

Volume 5, Number 2, Spring 1975

THE LATTICE OF TOPOLOGIES](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rmjm/1250130634)

[This paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1966-122-02/S0002-9947-1966-0190893-2/S0002-9947-1966-0190893-2.pdf) first(?) called them infraspaces, same definition. It predates the above paper by 9 years, which makes sense, as the RMJM paper is a survey of earlier results.

So "infraspaces" seems to be sort of accepted, though not widely known, really, as the lattice of topologies is not a very popular subject.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ..But I found other source that define the infraspace in different way than that you provided
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/312902737_ON_INFRA_TOPOLOGICAL_SPACES